# Confusing C# Constructor

Tags: c#

I ran across some code today that is a little confusing to me.  I have a class called Operator.  Help me understand what is happening in the constructor of the class.  I do not understand why it has the UsedImplicity attribute and I do not know what "*this(r => { })*" is accomplishing.

```
public class Operator
{
[NotNull] readonly IUnityContainer _container;
[NotNull] readonly ServerWrapper _server;

[UsedImplicitly]
public Operator()
  : this(r => { })
{
}
```

UPDATE - The other constructor:

```
public Operator([NotNull] Action<IUnityContainer> register)
{
  _container = new UnityContainer()
    .RegisterType<ISettingsReader, MessageBusSettingsReader>(
      new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
    .RegisterType<IImpersonationStrategyFactory, ImpersonationStrategyFactory>();

  register(_container);

  _operator= new OperatorWrapper(_container.Resolve<ISettingsReader>());
}
```

Comment: It calls another ctor overload with an `Operator(Action<SomeType>)` signature.

Comment: Beat me to it, please show all constructors on this class, and we can make it clear exactly what is being called, and when.

Comment: It surely derives from something else...or there were other ctors

Comment: The `UsedImplicitly` attribute is used by Resharper (and other tools) to say "This constructor **is** used, so don't mark it as unused".  - [the docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.2/Reference__Code_Annotation_Attributes.html#UsedImplicitlyAttribute) say it _"
Indicates that the marked symbol is used implicitly (e.g. via reflection, in external library), so this symbol will not be marked as unused (as well as by other usage inspections). "_

Comment: Open the Keyboard settings in VS (if you're in VS) and map the Edit.GoTo command to a rational keyboard shortcut (mine is ctrl-shft-G). Then, when you're wondering what the heck that thing over there is, just slap your cursor on it and Edit.GoTo see what's the deal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The constructor provides a callback mechanism: On instantiating an `Operator`, you as the caller may pass in a method pointer (lambda or not) with the `Action<IUnityContainer>` signature, that would be a `void Callback(IUnityContainer c)` for example, or a `c => { do_something_with_c(c); }`.

The default constructor, that is the one without arguments, chains the constructor with an empty method body, it basically ignores (throws away) the container callback. It does so because it needs to execute the initialization code in that second constructor, but cannot call it without its required argument.

Second subquestion: `UsedImplicitly` is to get rid of warnings when a symbol is never referenced but meant to be used by reflection or called externally, is well documented [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Reference__Code_Annotation_Attributes.html).